# Grails gsp/html: Invalid location of tag (li)

Tags: html, grails, gsp

I'm getting an error - Invalid location of tag (li) - in the first line of the following gsp/html code.

```
<li id="stackLIform2008">
<a class="stacked-nav-pill" onkeypress="loadStack('form2008'); return false" onclick="loadStack('form2008'); return false" href="#">Form 2008</a>
</li>
```

I don't understand what I'm overlooking.  Can someone help?  many thanks. -r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the `<li>` is held within a `<ul>` or `<ol>` block. Without including the surrounding code in the question it's difficult to say for sure, but that's what the error points to.

Comment: ok thanks.   It might have been the HTML validator bugging me - I've used <li> tags before without the <ul> listing and have been ok.  Many thanks for your help. :)

Comment: @ry1633 `<li>` tags should always be nested within `<ul>` or `<ol>`

Comment: Absolutely, a browser _may_ render them correctly but the standard says they need to be nested, see http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html. If this solves your problem it'd be great for an upvote/accept ;).